# After setting UIViewController size as freeform container view at the bottom disappeared

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

After setting the `UIViewController` size to freeform in `Storyboard`, container view at the bottom is not appearing. Container view (acts as a footer) is placed just below the `UIScrollView`.

However if I place it within the `UIScrollView` lower bounds, it does appear.

`UIViewController` height is 800. Its size is Freeform (in order to accommodate more controls) rather than Inferred.

```
Xcode version = 6.1.1
iOS version = 8.1
```

Comment: In freeform, what the frame size has been set (x, y, viewWidth, viewHeight)? Also what about the constraints setting for the same.

Comment: x=0, y=0, width=320, height=800

Comment: <= iPhone 5s height is 480, then how can it be possible to display the content added below it, are you using scrollview for user to scroll down?

Comment: i am using iPhone 6 simulator. Also to arrange controls, I had to make its height equals to 800. I am using scroll viewer. The container view is placed after the scroll viewer

Comment: Can you place your storyboard image into the question area?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not able to provide the screenshot now. But i can tell the dimension: main UIView (0,0,320,800). All the controls are added within UIScrollView which is nested inside the view (0,0,320,800). By the way, how can I fix the height of UIView in code? That may help.

Comment: you should give mainview and scrollview height as per screen height. Yes you can use setFrame method in viewDidLoad and change the frame.

Comment: Better option I would suggest you is to use height and top+bottom constraints if you are using storyboard for view designing. This will help us to adjust dimensions on proportional basis, so that developer need not to be worried about screen size.

Comment: Have you resolved this?